# Capture bytes sent by Webservice

Tags: .net, web-services, asmx, byte, httpmodule

I'm trying to get how many bytes my Webservice sending out.  I used very useful answer from this post ([IIS 7 managed module can't get Content-Length or bytes sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483979/iis-7-managed-module-cant-get-content-length-or-bytes-sent))  to create httpModule and attached to my webservice.  It sort of works, but it doesn't capture the length or the complex objects that are being serialized and sent out.   It seems that Xml-Serialized objects are being ignored.

P.S.  Once I attach the module to a website, I get expected results.

Please help

Comment: What kind of services are you using? ASMX or WCF? Which version of IIS are you using?

Comment: it ASMX with IIS7 ... and after a day of monitoring, I'm think I was wrong.  It seems that everything works as it was intended.

Answer (score 0):

Using IIS 7 special feature you can trace the request and response by logging the same.

for advanced logging have a look on this

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/579/advanced-logging-for-iis-70---custom-logging/

Hope this may help you.